# How should I separate entities methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework, architecture, linq-to-entities

Good people of SO,

Today I have some serious concerns on my business layer design.
It is based on Entity POCO objects and
I want to add logic to these entities BUT, there are 2 types of logic:

1. Pure C# logic
2. Persistence logic (LinqToEntities in my case)

My question is simple:

How should I **separate** these two kinds ?

First, I was thinking about adding these two as methods to the entities. And using **partial classes** to split them.

Second, I thought that I wouldn't want an **overweight object** with a LOT of methods.
So maybe why not static classes or singleton with methods doing the LinqToEntities stuff, and leave the pure C# in entity methods.
Then I would have **several classes grouped by fonctionnality providing the logic**, the entity is passed as argument to the classes methods.

It really bothers me, because the second solution seems cleaner but it looks like it breaks the object-oriented paradigm. On the other hand the first one seems like an anti-pattern.

What do you think ? Do you have a bright solution solving this paradox ?

**Schizophrenic edit**:  in fact what I call persistence logic should go to the DAL and the pure c# logic in the BLL. POCO entities are produced by the DAL. I can then extend these entities in my BLL to add methods. In my DAL I should structure the logic as exposed in the second solution.

Comment: Erm, why do you say 2nd method breaks the O-O paradigm? In what ways exactly? And is that your only concern with option 2?

Comment: In OO you send messages to the object. In the 2nd solution, you pass the object as parameter of a method that will do the job. It looks like OO emulation: static method with object as first argument.
This is my only concern, I just want to avoid an overweight entity.

Comment: In that case, your entities will be doing everything that is many times more than what a business entity should be. In anycase, I'm not in the best position to gauge that though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic that describes how an entity should be saved/loaded doesn't belong to the entity itself ; it's more likely to be the role of a persistence service, a data access object, etc.

I would let the object specific logic in the object -- we're here talking about the object behavior, then create a service that handles persistence concerns for this object type.

Comment: mmmh, I am in SOA, so I don't want to create a persistence service. It would break the architecture. See, this bll will be is a service, if this service MUST rely on a persistence service, then it won't be autonomous...

Comment: I think you're mixing different concepts here. Consider that the service you're talking about is *one component* of your SOA architecture. It's a granularity matter : this component has it's own design. When I'm talking about a persistence service, I'm not talking about another high level independent service of your SOA ecosystem -- I'm talking about a possible inner component of your existing service. The "persistence service" can be a simple class. Read "data access object" if you prefer.